# Returning data from a Linq to SQL query as a custom data type

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql

I've written a query in linq to return the information of 10 different employees based on the their employeenumber. I'm new to working wtih linq though and I'm having issues returning it. What am I doing wrong in this code?

```
 public class queryClass
    {
        private string firstName { get; set; }
        private string lastName { get; set; }
        private int employeeNo { get; set; }
        private string department { get; set; }
    }

    public static queryClass[] GetEmpData(int empID1, int empID2, int empID3, int empID4, int empID5, int empID6, int empID7, int empID8, int empID9, int empID10)
    {

        using(var context = new EmpInfoDataContext())
        {
            var query = from e in context.EmployeTable
                        join j in context.JobTitles on e.JobTitle equals j.JobTitle
                        where e.EmployeeNo == empID1
                        where e.EmployeeNo == empID2
                        where e.EmployeeNo == empID3
                        where e.EmployeeNo == empID4
                        where e.EmployeeNo == empID5
                        where e.EmployeeNo == empID6
                        where e.EmployeeNo == empID7
                        where e.EmployeeNo == empID8
                        where e.EmployeeNo == empID9
                        where e.EmployeeNo == empID10
                        select new  {e.FirstName, e.LastName, e.EmployeeNo, j.Department};

            return query.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

Under the 'return query.Toarray();" the error is "Cannot convert expression type '{FirstName:string, LastName:string, EmployeeNo:int, Department:string}[] to return type 'Employeephotos.Models.HomeModel.queryClass[]"

Thanks for any help you can give.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your where clause should be a single boolean expression.

```
where e.EmployeeNo == empID1 || e.EmployeeNo == empID2 ... etc
```

and Make sure you declare the type of your selected items

```
select new queryClass {
    firstName = e.FirstName,
    lastName = e.LastName,
    employeeNo = e.EmployeeNo,
    department = j.Department
};
```

Comment: thanks, I'm still trying to figure it all out. The error I'm having though is that the "return query.ToArray()" is underlined in red and giving the error "Cannot convert expression type '{FirstName:string, LastName:string, EmployeeNo:int, Department:string}[] to return type 'Employeephotos.Models.HomeModel.queryClass[]" I'll edit the question to make this more clear

Comment: @Danger_Fox I've updated my answer to show you how to use your queryClass type in the select statement.

Answer (score 2):

`select new  {e.FirstName, e.LastName, e.EmployeeNo, j.Department};` is returning anonymous type

change it to return queryClass

```
select new  queryClass {firstName = e.FirstName, lastName =  e.LastName, employeeNo =e.EmployeeNo, department = j.Department};
```